# Added Many2Many now getting "ValueError: XXX needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've read a bunch of similar sounding questions of SO, but somehow none of them have helped me solve my particular case. I added a `ManyToManyField` to represent "Likes" to my `Photo` model:

```
class Photo(TimestampModerated):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='description of entity', blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, height_field="height", width_field="width", blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, null=True)
    size = models.BigIntegerField('size of file in bytes', blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "photos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        default_storage.delete("{}".format(self.photo))
        super().delete()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the view (at least the part that should matter for creating):

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly, permissions.AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, likes=[])
```

And here is the serializer:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, TaggitSerializer):
    owner = serializers.CharField(source='owner.username', read_only=True)
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    photo = Base64ImageField(
        max_length=None, use_url=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('photo', 'height', 'width', 'owner', 'slug', 'uuid', 'title', 'id', 'created', 'updated',
                  'moderation_code', 'tags', 'hash', 'description', 'size', 'likes')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        photo = Photo.objects.create(owner=validated_data.pop('owner'),
                                     **validated_data)
        p = Photo.objects.get(uuid=photo.uuid)
        [p.tags.add(tag) for tag in validated_data['tags']]
        return photo
```

To be clear, the only thing that has been added is the `likes` field in the model. Also, I should note that I am able to actually POST new likes to photos that already existed in the DB before the migration. I'm just having issues creating new instances. Any ideas?

Here is the full error traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/photos/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 86, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/photos/views.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, likes=[])
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 215, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/photos/serializers.py", line 88, in create
    **validated_data)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 566, in __init__
    _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 536, in __set__
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 513, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/_/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 830, in __init__
    (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
ValueError: "<Photo: photo-260561.jpeg>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: You need to first create/save the photo object, when then add many-to-many relations of likes. If photo object is not saved, i.e. it does not have 'id', foreignkey of M2M relationships cannot be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this with one seemingly very simple line of code:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data.pop('likes') ## adding this line solved the issue 
    photo = Photo.objects.create(owner=validated_data.pop('owner'),
                                 **validated_data)
    p = Photo.objects.get(uuid=photo.uuid)
    [p.tags.add(tag) for tag in validated_data['tags']]
    return photo
```

If anyone can explain why this works, I'd be interested to know. I should point out that for this use case a photo would never be initiated with likes.

Comment: It works because you remove `likes` from `validated_data`. Since you create your photo with `**validated_data`, if `likes` are still in it, it tries to associate the likes to a photo that doesn't have an `id` yet. You have to `1) create the photo`, `2) associate the likes`. Both cannot be done in the same time.

Comment: Additional advice : `[p.tags.add(tag) for tag in validated_data['tags']]` why do you do a list comprehension here ? It produces an useless list. You'd better do it the usual way : `for tag in validated_data['tags']: p.tags.add(tag)`